# How do I fire a function when 2 divs are tapped at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up a HTML game that involves players clicking on 2 different divs at the same time. How do I activate a function when 2 divs with the same class are tapped?

So far, I have each div working individually, however, when I tap both, neither click event is fired.

```
$( ".tile" ).click(function() {
    value++;
    $( ".score" ).text( value );
});
```

I am wanting var value to increase only when the 2 tile divs are tapped together.

Comment: In a single frame its impossible to click two divs.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you describe.

Comment: You cannot do this with `click` or with jQuery. You need to use the [multitouch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Multi-touch_interaction).